# Cannot connect to a WSL based GridDB Deployment

Tags: griddb

I am trying to connect the HeidiSQL client to WSL based installed Griddb.

I setup the GridDB server on a WSL Ubuntu image, Host and can successfully connect via the sqlwbconsole from within the container, but having problem connecting from the host via the HeidiSQL. I am suspecting that the problem is with docker not supporting Clients and found that using --network host should fix the problem. But still cannot connect to the database.

How can I connect HeidiSQL client to my locally configured Griddb.

When i am trying to connect it using default creds it is showing the below error:

```
Can't connect to server on 'localhost' (10060)query
```

Does it support connecting to various SQL clients?